# How to call a function in a class of another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following the code in data.py

```
import numpy as np

from scipy import stats

class Data:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """ (Data, list, list) -> NoneType

        Create a new data object with two attributes: x and y.
        """
        self.x = x
        self.y = y



    def compute_least_squares_fit(self):
        """ (Data) -> number, number

        Return the intercept and slope of the simple linear regression fit
        of the data.
        """

        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(self.x,self.y)
        return slope, intercept

    def compute_SST(self):
        """ (Data) -> number

        Return the sum of squares total (SST).
        """

        avg_y = np.mean(self.y)
        squared_errors = (self.y - avg_y) ** 2
        return np.sum(squared_errors)
```

I have this code on the other file

```
import numpy as np

from scipy import stats

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from data import Data


class SLR:

    def __init__(self, data):
        """ (SLR, Data) -> NoneType

        Create a new simple linear regression object from data,
        with data data, intercept beta0, and slope beta1.



        """
```

How can I use the intercept and slope from the another file on to this one?

Comment: In your `__init__` method you have a parameter `data` that should be an instance of `Data`. Now call `data.compute_least_squares_fit()` and use the return values.

Comment: Thank you but how to return the values? Can I use intercept and slope variables directly?